# DBaaS concept for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, daas

I need to create a Database as a Service (DBaaS) concept for our Datacenter. Currently we have everything of VMware – but this is not really a DaaS concept I think. Corporate policy does not allow public cloud solutions. Is it possible to implement something like Azure SQL Database in your own datacenter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course it's possible. Microsoft's done it in their datacentres, you can do it in yours. It may take some time and effort however. :-)

There is not yet an Azure on-prem product. I've read rumours of one due in the next year or so. Either way, it will take a while to be fully functional and licensing not going to be cheap.

Best bet would be to roll out the DevOps toolkit. Infrastructure as code; desired state configuration; pre-speced VM images produced from a pick list; automated on-demand app deployment. All the bits are around and open source. Linking them will take a few dedicated months. Getting management approval, and educating users to take responsibility for their usage may take longer.

---

In July 2017 Microsoft [announced](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/microsoft-azure-stack-is-ready-to-order-now/) Azure Stack, which makes their cloud management software available for on-premises deployment. Included in this is [SQL databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-stack/azure-stack-tutorial-sql-server).

Comment: Powershell - https://dbatools.io/ for automation!

Answer (score 1):

In general look for Hyper-Converged Infrastructures. (HCI)

- [VMware Hyper-Converged Infrastructure](http://VMware%20Hyper-Converged%20Infrastructure)
- [XCP Xen Cloud Platform](https://wiki.xen.org/wiki/XCP_Overview) (Open source)
- [Nutanix](https://www.nutanix.com/)
- [DELL EMC VXRail](https://www.emc.com/en-us/converged-infrastructure/vxrail/index.htm#collapse=&tab3=0)